# Returning unchanged tokens from a parseAction generates doubly nested dictionaries

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

Attaching a parse action, which only returns the tokens, to a parser, which generates a single group in the ParseResults list, produces a doubly nested dictionary (result3).

I posted this question in the [pyparsing GitHub issues page](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/issues/22) seeing it as an inconsistency. But maybe it is not, and I just do not understand ParseResults objects. Below I have expanded my observations slightly.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from pyparsing import *

name = Word(alphas)('name')
score = Word(nums + '.')('score')
nameScore = Group(name + score)
line1 = nameScore('Rider')
line2 = nameScore('Rider') + nameScore('Bull')

result1 = line1.parseString('Mauney 46.5')
result2 = line2.parseString('Mauney 46.5 Asteroid 46')

print("### before parse action is added ###")
print("result1.dump():\n" + result1.dump() + "\n")
print("result2.dump():\n" + result2.dump() + "\n")

line1.setParseAction(lambda t: t)
line2.setParseAction(lambda t: t)

result3 = line1.parseString('Mauney 46.5')
result4 = line2.parseString('Mauney 46.5 Asteroid 46')

print("### after parse action was added ###")
print("result3.dump():\n" + result3.dump() + "\n")
print("result4.dump():\n" + result4.dump() + "\n")
```

Executing the above results in the following.

```
### before parse action is added ###
result1.dump():
[['Mauney', '46.5']]
- Rider: ['Mauney', '46.5']
  - name: 'Mauney'
  - score: '46.5'

result2.dump():
[['Mauney', '46.5'], ['Asteroid', '46']]
- Bull: ['Asteroid', '46']
  - name: 'Asteroid'
  - score: '46'
- Rider: ['Mauney', '46.5']
  - name: 'Mauney'
  - score: '46.5'

### after parse action was added ###
result3.dump():
[['Mauney', '46.5']]
- Rider: [['Mauney', '46.5']]   <=================
  - Rider: ['Mauney', '46.5']
    - name: 'Mauney'
    - score: '46.5'

result4.dump():
[['Mauney', '46.5'], ['Asteroid', '46']]
- Bull: ['Asteroid', '46']
  - name: 'Asteroid'
  - score: '46'
- Rider: ['Mauney', '46.5']
  - name: 'Mauney'
  - score: '46.5'
```

It appears that the outermost ParseResults object is part of its own dictionary.

Is this expected behaviour, and if so, why is it happening?

**Some further observations.**

If the ParseResults list contains two groups there is no double nesting (result2).

If the parse action for `line1` is changed to

```
line1.setParseAction(lambda t: [t[0]])
```

the desired result is obtained:

```
result1.dump():
[['Mauney', '46.5']]
- Rider: ['Mauney', '46.5']
  - name: 'Mauney'
  - score: '46.5'
```

Comment: The logic in handling ParseResults gets tricky since we try to populate them in a flat list, and only introduce hierarchy if there is an explicit Group expression. This is the source of the up-propagation of results names, since `And([And([A, B]), C])` expressions need to report the same results as `And([A, B, C])`.

Thanks for the test cases, I will try to clean this up while retaining backwards compatibility of the intended behavior (still might require a `2.x+1` point release, since it looks like it would change some returned ParseResults structures for existing code).

Comment: This is in fact a bug in pyparsing, and will be fixed in a future release.  For now, if you want your parse actions to retain the original nesting level, have them return `None`, so that pyparsing will use the original ParseResults, rather than try to create a new one with the additional nesting level.